# Add Locations menu item

Tags: menu

I seem to recall that some version of Mathematica had a "Locations" (or was it "Places"?) item on its menu, which listed common folders that one might want to open easily -- and that there was even a way to extend the list.

This seems to have disappeared in 11.3.

Is there some way to recreate it?

Comment: This looks like the kind of thing you'll want to do some spelunking for. I can't right now, but [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133851/what-are-all-the-possible-menu-edits) answer and related links gives you the best control over it. I also have some stuff that uses that to add any key binding you want [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180726/38205) and the linked package could help make this easier.

Comment: @b3m2a1: It's not keybinding I'm after, but an actual new main Mathematica menu item.

Comment: I know. That answer does key bindings *using* a brand new menu.

Comment: I guess that is the answer you are looking for: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109396/5478

Comment: @Kuba looks like it.

Comment: @murray can we mark it as a duplicate?

Comment: @Yes, mark as duplicate! (I just didn't find that when searching,)